# Как сделать one to one undirectional mapping hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Я имею следующую схему БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из картинки Card_balance ссылается на Cards. Мне нужно чтобы при переходе в ORM у сущности Cards было поле Card_balance, и была однонаправленная связь, при которой Cards ссылается на Card_balance.
Я пытался сделать это следующим образом:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
public class Cards implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CARDS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CARDS_SEQ", sequenceName = "CARDS_SEQ")
    private Long cardId;

    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CARD_ID", nullable = false)
    private CardBalance cardBalance;
```

а в card_balance добавил поле cardId

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "CARD_BALANCE")
public class CardBalance {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BALANCE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ", sequenceName = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ")
    private Long balanceId;

    ...

    @Column(name="CARD_ID")
    private Long cardId;
```

Но данный способ не сработал, так как при извлечение из бд cards я получаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать mappedBy http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы путаетесь в понятиях. На диаграмме между `CAPTAIN.CARDS` и `CAPTAIN.CARD_BALANCE` связь не один к одному, а один ко многим. Не ясно выходит маппинг в классе `Cards`, сначала вы определяете колонку `CARD_ID` с Id самой сущности, а ниже определяете еще одну колонку `CARD_ID` с ссылкой на `CardBalance`. Попробуйте, переименуйте вторую, например, в BALANCE_ID так:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BALANCE_ID", nullable = false)
private CardBalance cardBalance;
```